# Find corresponding values in Excel file with python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In my Excel file Column B is an aggregate cell containing all values in the same rows.

When a new value is entered I need to match it with the data in column B  between - and >.
Whenever the values in column B between - and > is exactly the same as the new number, it is expected to return the corresponding letter in column A and the corresponding day & time in column C/D/E.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G188k.png)

For example;

if `33` is entered:-

- it is expected to first find values ONLY in column B between - and >. No need to search column A.
- then it will return Y in column A
- and 20/07 day in column C.

If `55` is entered:-

- it is expected to first find values  ONLY in column B between - and >. No need to search column A.
- then it will return W in column A
- and 18/07 day in column E.

[The excel file has hundreds of rows and columns]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it  only need to search column B as it is aggregate cells containing all values previously entered. i have changed the data to make it easier to understand. Whether matches are foound or not, it will be entered into cell under coresonding day. no other actions to be taken.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear if/where you are extracting information.
Example 1
***if 33 is entered:-

it is expected to first find values ONLY in column B between - and >. No need to search column A.***
OK so I enter a value of 33 and search for `-33>` in all the cells in Column B from row 1 to row (unknown). Using the example data I find a match in B4
`173-21>[21/07 21:19:30]+173-33>[20/07 14:19:30]+173-7>[19/07 14:19:30]`
 at this point
`+173-33>`
***then it will return Y in column A***
In column A for the same row 4 the value is `'Y'` so I can guess we can simply look in the corresponding Column A cell for that value.
***and 20/07 day in column C.***
How is this determined? Why are we looking in column 'C' and not 'D' or 'E'. Do we need to search C, D & E for a match to `-33>` as well so it's Column C that we want? Or is it necessary at all and we just need to extract the date `20/07` from the bracketed data after the value, i.e. `[20/07 14:19:30]`?
This date is the date you show in the example.

With the second example, 55 the same goes;
55 is found in the text `'195-35>[16/07 09:44:35]+195-65>[17/07 09:44:35]+195- 55>[18/07 09:44:35]'` in cell `'B3'`. The column A value is `'W'` and the date in brackets next to the found number is `[18/07 09:44:35]` i.e. `'18/07'`, which matches you example 2 expectations but again why do we look in Column E for the date?

However with the search value 55, it is also found in cell `'B5'` so why don't we use that instead/as well?

Also not sure what your end result is, are you extracting the data from Column B to update columns 'C, D, E & etc' so we really are only looking Column B?

I have put together the following code example and wrapped in the two example search values to show the output for these input values.
In real life you'd want to remove the for

```
for search_num in test_list:
```

loop and enable the line

```
# search_num = int(input("Enter search number "))
```

to allow users to enter the number to search.

In this code sample the two values are searched in Column B one after the other.
The code checks for the pattern `'-{search number}>'` in the cell text first. If it's not found then move to the next row. If its found then the date value is extracted from the date value in square brackets next to the found value.
The value from Column A is also extracted.
As mentioned I do not know what your end requirement is so have placed the values into a dictionary keyed by the search number.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re


wb = load_workbook("data.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

### Ask user of number to search
# search_num = int(input("Enter search number "))

data_dict = {}

### Run test on the two example inputs
for search_num in [33, 55]:
    search_pattern = f'-{search_num}>'
    for cell in ws['B']:
        if cell.row == 1:  # Skip the first row [Header]
            continue
        cv = cell.value
        ### Check if the search number format exists in the cell text
        if search_pattern in cv:
            print(f"The search pattern '{search_pattern}' was found in the cell text '{cv}'!")

            ### regex to extract the date value next to the found search
            pattern2 = f'(?<={search_pattern}\[)\d+\/\d+'
            date_value = re.findall(pattern2, cv)[0]

            ### extract the value from Column A current row
            col_a_value = ws[f'A{cell.row}'].value

            ### Add details to the dictionary
            if search_num not in data_dict.keys():
                data_dict[search_num] = [date_value, col_a_value]
            else:
                data_dict[f'{search_num}a'] = [date_value, col_a_value]

print("Dictionary")
print(data_dict)
```

**Output**
As mentioned I don't know what your end requirement is, I have used a dictionary to capture the extracted data for the code example which may not be what you want to you'd need to change the code to do whatever it is you require.
Dictionary data_dict

```
{
  33: ['20/07', 'Y'], 
  55: ['18/07', 'W'], 
  '55a': ['22/07', 'Z']
}
```

As you can see the expected data is extracted, However as noted, '55' occurs in Column B twice so two lots of data is extracted. I have set the code to assign that as key '55a' as a one off.
I don't know if such a situation is expected or how you want it handled if it does.

***If your requirement is only to extract data from the sheet and not write/update any values depending on just how big the sheet is you may find opening the workbook as 'read only` will improve performance. If the workbook is opened as 'read only' you will not be able to write to it.***